# jProfiler can't find JVM

Tags: java, jvm, jprofiler

I've started jprofiler on my production server and after some profiling I've killed it (kill -9 ).

Now I'm trying to start it again and receive only "No unprofiled JVMs found." message,
but jps command says that my application is running (and I can see that it works by myself actually).

Probably jprofiler stores info about which jvms it profiles at the moment in some file and
kill command prevented it from updating this file. So how can I clean it manually?

p.s. I've tried to delete and then unpack jprofile again, still not working.

Comment: `kill -9` doesn't give the target process a chance to clean up (like, you know, properly unregister from the target JVM for instance). Only use it when a plain kill hasn't worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JProfiler finds JVMs via the "Attach API" that is part of the JDK. Have a look at the `$TMP/hsperfdata_$USER` directory, which is created by the hot spot JVM. It should contain PID files for all running JVMs. If not, delete the directory and restart all JVMs.

Comment: Just a note for anyone who might have the same problem as me: if you're using cygwin on Windows, it uses a different tmp directory so JProfiler won't be able to find the PID files. Try using cmd prompt instead.

Comment: In my case, directory `hsperfdata_$USER` doesn't contain any files for some reason. Deletion of this folder didn't help. After a restart of JVM new empty directory is created. Do you have any ideas on how to solve this problem? I'm using Websphere

Comment: The attach mechanism only works for Hotspot JVMs, not for IBM JVMs.

Comment: For OpenJDK 1.8.0_151-b12 also? OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: Yes, it should work for all OpenJDK JVMs. Maybe the temp directory has been set to a non-standard directory for the process?

Answer (score 1):

[look at this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280315/how-to-detach-jprofiler8-jpenable-remote-agent), it is not possible to unload a Jprofiler agent on a java process unless you kill the jp.

I'm not sure if you can really kill the agent.

"No unprofiled JVMs found." message will occur when you start Jprofiler twice.
Try to restart the monitored java application.

Answer (score 0):

On the WLS server, this usually means that you restarted the server and have two JVMs rumming.
I run this to start jpenable:
**./jpenable --gui --port=8888 --pid=$WLS_ID**
and get this error:
**The JVM with PID 14690 is not unprofiled.**

Kill the one listed:
**kill -9 14690**

Rerun the jpenable startup command above with this output:
**Connecting to weblogic.Server [18037] ...
You can now use the JProfiler GUI to connect on port 8888**

**18037** is the PID of the JVM that can not be connected with the JProfiler client