# No unprofiled JVM found

Tags: jprofiler

I have `WebSphere 7` Aplication Server. There is `Java VM 1.6` installed. `Linux`.

Java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6460sr10fp1-20120321_01(SR10 FP1))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Linux amd64-64 jvmxa6460sr10fp1-20120202_101568 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20120202_101568
JIT  - r9_20111107_21307ifx1
GC   - 20120202_AA)
JCL  - 20120320_01

I try to use `jProfiler`, using trial lisence. But don't want to change something on the server this time.

So I download `jprofiler` for linux to my server.

Then I run `bin/jpenable` and it says that:

```
No unprofiled JVM found
```

Now I don't know what to do, googling doesn't give any useful result. Can You tell me in what way I must search a problem? May be incorrect path or something else. I hope You'll understand my english (it is not so good).

Comment: what's your `java -version` output? add it to your question

Comment: java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6460sr10fp1-20120321_01(SR10 FP1))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Linux amd64-64 jvmxa6460sr10fp1-20120202_101568 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20120202_101568
JIT  - r9_20111107_21307ifx1
GC   - 20120202_AA)
JCL  - 20120320_01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [help pdf](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/help.pdf), in specifically check out `Attach to local JVM session`.

Also, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160368/jprofiler-cant-find-jvm#9176742) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053484/how-to-connect-jprofiler-to-an-application-running-on-localhost).

hope it will help..

Comment: I used "bin/jpintegrate" script to install jprofiler on my Websphere 7. There was just one error when I restart my application server. In server.xml (it was modidfied by "bin/jpintegrate") agent_path was path to the linux_x86, but my system is x64 (I don't know why it add linux_x86 path, but jpintegrate didn't ask me about it). So I changed it to x64, and my application server start successfully. Then i copied config.xml (created by jpintegrate) to my Windows machine and "import session" and then connect to the jpprofiler agent on WebSphere. Thank You.