# How to detach Jprofiler8 'jpenable' remote agent

Tags: jprofiler

Since I need to profile the application runs in remote machine where GUI is not allowed. I started remote session profiling with JProfiler8 and ran **/bin/jpenable** agent in remote host. After the successful analysis I need to stop that remote jpenable jprofiler8 agent. How can I do that?

To make sure previously started agent is still in running state or not, I ran the /bin/jpenable agent again. Now I don't see previously binded JVM. So i assume it already bind with previous agent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to unload a JVMTI profiling agent. The JVM only unloads agents when it shuts down.